# Evaluating expression tree using std::map<std::string, int>

Tags: c++, dictionary, tree, expression

I am not sure how to use the map function to evaluate my tree expression. The function goes like this

```
int Tree::evaluate(std::map< std::string, int > ipMap){
```

My teacher gave me a hint to look at my function to postorder print for an example but I am not sure how it applies to this. Here it is:

```
void Tree::postOrderPrint(){
if(NodeType==TYPE_OPERATOR)
{
    leftPtr->postOrderPrint();
    rightPtr->postOrderPrint();
    std::cout<< Op << "  " ;
}
else
{
    std::cout<< Op << "  " ;
}

}
```

What if the tree is already built, string parsed from previous functions and really all this function has do to is something equivalent to the following function

```
int arithmetic_expression::evaluateTree(TreeNodePtr rootPtr)
{
if ((rootPtr->Op=="+") | (rootPtr->Op=="-")|(rootPtr->Op=="*")|(rootPtr->Op== "/")) 
{
    if (rootPtr->Op=="+")
        {
            return(evaluateTree(rootPtr->leftPtr)+ evaluateTree(rootPtr->rightPtr));
        }
    if (rootPtr->Op=="-")
    {
        return(evaluateTree(rootPtr->leftPtr)- evaluateTree(rootPtr->rightPtr));
    }
    if (rootPtr->Op=="*")
    {
        return(evaluateTree(rootPtr->leftPtr)* evaluateTree(rootPtr->rightPtr));
    }
    if (rootPtr->Op=="/")
    {
        return(evaluateTree(rootPtr->leftPtr)/ evaluateTree(rootPtr->rightPtr));
    }
}
else
{
    int Number;
    std::istringstream(rootPtr->Op) >> Number;
    return(Number);
}

}
```

Here is what is calling the function:

```
int arithmetic_expression::evaluate_Expression(std::map< std::string, int > ipMap)
{
if (tree != NULL){
    return(tree->evaluate(ipMap));
}
else
    return(0);

}
```

Does this look like it would make sense?

```
int Tree::evaluate(std::map< std::string, int > ipMap){


std::map<std::string, int >::iterator myIter;
myIter=ipMap.find(Op);


{
    if (myIter=="+")
    {
    return(evaluate(leftPtr)+ evaluate(rightPtr))

    }
    if (myIter=="-")
    {
    return(evaluate(leftPtr)- evaluate(rightPtr));
    }
    if (myIter=="*")
    {
    return(evaluate(leftPtr)* evaluate(rightPtr));
    }
    if (myIter=="/")
    {
    return(evaluate(leftPtr)/ evaluate(rightPtr));
    }
    }
    else{
```

Comment: What are the roles of the `string` and `int` in the map?

Comment: okay what i tried was wrong. but im just supposed to use map to find if the element in the tree expression is a + - * or / i believe, and if so use that operator to evaluate the left aand right subtrees

Comment: I still don't see how you want to/need to use the map...  To begin with: What is it mapping from and what is it mapping to?  And I don't mean the types (string and int)

Comment: mapping things like "(A + B - C * D) / E + (F - 3)" "1 + (2 * 3)" and in expression tree format, its a infix postfix program

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments the map holds an expression and you need to update the associated value with the result of that expression.  To achieve this, you will need to parse the string and build the expression tree before you can evaluate it.

```
int Tree::evaluate(std::map< std::string, int > ipMap){
  std::map< std::string, int >::iterator it;
  for (it=ipMap.begin(); it != ipMap.end(); ++it) {
    Tree tree;
    tree.parse(it->first);
    *it = tree.postOrderEvaluate();
  }
}
```

Since you are not tied to any particular tree in your `evaluate` function, it could be a static member function (or a free function).

`int Tree:postOrderEvaluate()` would go along the lines of `Tree:postOrderPrint()`: 1) evaluate the left sub-tree, 2) evaluate the right sub-tree, 3) perform the operation on the two results, 4) return the result of the current sub-tree.

Comment: thank you for this, but what if its already parsed, and the tree is already built from other functions?

Comment: Unless you have a way of retrieving the already parsed tree from the string, you will need to parse it again.  You could store all parsed trees in a `map<string, Tree>`, then retrieve the tree by looking up the currect string.  Or are you asking about `postOrderEvaluate()`?

Comment: there is just one function to evaluate the expression trees. no postorderevaluate or inorder evaluate. i think i am just asking how to use the map to recognize +-*/ from numbers and variables and based on what it is evaluate the left ptr and right ptr of the tree  based on that. updated OP showing the function that calls the evaluate function

Comment: I think I am begining to understand your question :)  If i'm correct, you want to convert the tree to a string and associate that string with the result of the expression (represented by the tree) in the map.  In that case you have the to-string logic in `prostOrderPrint`, and you can put the logic of what I described as `postOrderEvaluate` (pretty much the same as `arithmetic_expression::evaluateTree`) to the `evaluate` function and store the results in the map: `ipMap[str]=result;`

Comment: Based on what you said about the contents of the map, you will not find the operand in the map keys: the keys are full expressions.  Instead you need to calculate that expression by using a logic similar to `postOrderTree` that actually returns the string (instead of printing it to console) from the current tree.  Then evaluate the expression via `arithmetic_expression::evaluateTree()` on the current tree and store the two results (string and int) in the map.  Unless I am still lost about what you actually try to achieve